# Qual é o intervalo máximo em milissegundos que pode ser utilizado no setInterval do JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber qual o intervalo máximo que pode ser utilizado no método **setInterval** do JavaScript.

Pergunto isso, pois usei o o setInterval da forma abaixo e ele não executou. Não sei se é algo no código ou algum limite de tempo que o setInterval tenha.

```js
//Aqui repitimos a função de cima a cada 60 segundos 
let logar_usuario = setInterval(logarUsuario, 60000);


function logarUsuario() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../banco/atualizar-log-usuario/deixar-usuario-logado.php",
    cache: false

  }).done(function() {


  }).fail(function() {


  }).always(function(data) {


  });
}
```

- No caso, eu gostaria de chamar a função a cada 60 segundos. Não sei se o setInterval() suporta esse intervalo todo de tempo.

Comment: A princípio não há limite (pelo menos não conheço). 60 segundos é muito pouco, e com certeza suporta esse valor. Se o seu código não funciona, o problema deve ser outro.

Comment: Também executei o snippet acima e esperei 60 segundos e veio resposta normalmente. Como eu disse, o problema pode ser outro. Diminua o tempo para 10 segundos e veja se aparece algo no console após 10 segundos.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Como podemos ver na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) desse método, há, sim, um limite para o argumento passado para ele:

### Valor máximo de atraso (Maximum delay value)

> O argumento é convertido para um inteiro de 32 bits signed (que suporta um intervalo que vai de um número negativo a um positivo). Isto limita o argumento a 2147483647 milissegundos.

Portanto, o maior número positivo que se pode passar para o método é **2147483647**, que é muito maior que o número que você passou (**60000**). Desta forma, o problema está, provavelmente, em outra parte do código.

Comment: Bacana! Não havia visto essa informação. Só por curiosidade, esse valor daria mais de 596 mil horas e mais de 68 anos :D

Comment: Show de bola, emanoellucas. Obrigado!

Comment: E pelo que li na documentação, segue o mesmo princípio para o setTimeout().

Comment: @sam isso seria em segundos, é mil vezes menos, mas ainda dá quase um mês...

Comment: Ai vai lá um carinha e dá um downvote na pergunta. Com nenhum motivo aparerente. Isso é vacilo.